# How to import angular flex-layout properly?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Can't find any solution over the internet. Did someone experience the same issue importing flex-layout?

> ./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/fesm2020/angular-flex-layout-core.mjs:2551:229-249
>
> - Error: export 'distinctUntilChanged' (imported as 'distinctUntilChanged') was not found in 'rxjs' (possible exports:
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeError, AsyncSubject, BehaviorSubject,
>   ConnectableObservable, EMPTY, EmptyError, GroupedObservable, NEVER,
>   Notification, NotificationKind, ObjectUnsubscribedError, Observable,
>   ReplaySubject, Scheduler, Subject, Subscriber, Subscription,
>   TimeoutError, UnsubscriptionError, VirtualAction,
>   VirtualTimeScheduler, animationFrame, animationFrameScheduler, asap,
>   asapScheduler, async, asyncScheduler, bindCallback, bindNodeCallback,
>   combineLatest, concat, config, defer, empty, forkJoin, from,
>   fromEvent, fromEventPattern, generate, identity, iif, interval,
>   isObservable, merge, never, noop, observable, of, onErrorResumeNext,
>   pairs, partition, pipe, queue, queueScheduler, race, range, scheduled,
>   throwError, timer, using, zip)

Comment: what version of angular and flex-layout you are using ? check in package.json file.

Comment: Which version of RxJs you have installed? Which version of RxJs is required by the version of @angular/flex-layout you are using?

Comment: @GRD I'm using angular 12 and flex-layout is 13

Comment: "rxjs": "~6.6.0",

Comment: @DanielBristol Use flex-layout 12 with angular version 12, remove flex-layout 13 and install version 12 using `npm i @angular/flex-layout@12`

Comment: @GRD it worked! I thought it has something to do with rxjs. Thank you

Comment: @DanielBristol Great! If you want further connect with me then you can send me email `grdtechlab@gmail.com` Thanks! Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue minutes ago. This happened after the Flex Layout lib was updated to 13.0.0-beta.37. If you return it to 13.0.0-beta.36 your project  will compile without any issue.

Comment: Yes you're right. I haven't notice the change. Its working fine like a few weeks ago but I reinstall the flex-layout without specifying the version and the issue came up

Comment: Here is issue in repo so the team knows about the issue: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1392

Answer (score 1):

First In your terminal window, use the following command inside your Angular project.

```
npm i @angular/flex-layout
```

Next, import FlexLayoutModule in your app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After that you can use it in your project like that:

```
<div class="container"
     fxLayout
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="center"
     fxLayoutGap="10px"
     fxLayoutGap.xs="0"
>
  <div class="item item-1">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    Item 3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container"
     fxLayout
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="center"
     fxLayoutGap="10px"
     fxLayoutGap.xs="0"
>
  <div class="item item-4">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item item-5">
    Item 5
  </div>
```